# Сложная группировка по условию

Tags: sql

Есть такая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE "table" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL,
  "edit_date" date,
  "app_date" date,
  "app_id" int4,
  "status" varchar(255)
)
```

Запрос для получения status актуальной записи:

```
SELECT
    app_id, status
FROM
    table 
WHERE
    app_id = 1 
ORDER BY
    app_date DESC,
    edit_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Т.е для app_id сортируем по двум полям и выбираем максимальную запись.

Мне нужно вместо одного app_id передать список, что-то типа:

```
   SELECT
        app_id, status
    FROM
        table 
    WHERE
        app_id in (...) 
    ORDER BY
        app_date DESC,
        edit_date DESC
    ...
```

Т.е. для каждой app_id из списка получить такую строку, где даты будут максимальны у двух полей.
Это можно сделать средствами group by или вложенным запросом?

СУБД - postgreSQL 10, но интересует запрос на чистом sql

Comment: Укажите конкретную СУБД, включая версию. А обычный подход - `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY app_id ORDER BY app_date DESC, edit_date DESC)` в CTE.

Comment: ставлю на postgres

Comment: @teran из-за кавычек поди?

Comment: @Akina `limit` еще

Comment: `first_value()` еще можно взять?